# How can I make a link act as a input type?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

I need to ask for help with the following:

I got a form text field where i inputted key presses via images like this:

```
<input type="image" src="key_q.png" id="key_q" />
```

How do I achieve the same function but in `<a href>` (when clicking link in this example a "q" should be pushed into the textfield)?

Comment: That code won't cause a q to be added to a textfield

Comment: `<input type="image"  ... />` is a graphical submit button. You could attach an `onclick`(/`onkeypress`?) event handler to the `input` to do the stuff you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with JavaScript:

```
<input type=image src=key_1.png id=key_q onclick="addLetter('q')" />
```

And somewhere within a `script` tag on your page:

```
function addLetter(var letter){
  var textField = document.getElementById('textfield');
  textField.innerHTML = textField.innerHTML + letter;
}
```

This assumes that you are using a `textarea` element. If it is a regular text field, use `textField.value` instead.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can make a function to add a letter every time an input image with a certain class is clicked. It's a little too early in the morning for me to think of and test the exact code required, but hopefully somebody will expand on this.

Comment: You could also do that with pure JavaScript, with not a lot of extra code.